# What's the difference between a kernel process and a user process?

Tags: linux-kernel, process

From kernel's perspective, what is a definitive difference between a kernel process and a user process?

I can think of a couple ways to tell the two apart:

1. a user process has a non-`NULL` `task_struct->mm`, while for a kernel process this field as `NULL`.
2. a user process does not have `PF_KTHREAD` set in `task_struct->flags`, while a kernel process does.

Are these differentiators definitive? Any other differences?

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481055/what-is-a-kernel-thread